# What are the best graphics cards for cycles?

Tags: cycles-render-engine, gpu, performance

I'm considering having a system build solely for rendering for cycles (as kind of a single PC renderfarm). Since the GPUs would be most important here, I plan on having it build around those. I was wondering what would be the best GPU to go for? As far as I can find, 2 gtx 580's seem to be the best option, while two 560 ti's give more bang for the buck. Any chance newer videocards work as well? (600+series?)

Comment: This is considered [off-topic](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/), try [blenderartists](http://www.blenderartists.org/forum/).

Comment: @Aldrik, perhaps a [canonical answer](http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/a/184/12) would be more useful, as this will be asked many more times.

Comment: @zeffii I don't think so, answers will quickly become out of date and useless to other users.

Comment: canonical answers can include statements like 'this is time bound information, answers can change over a matter of weeks or months.' Spreadsheet as linked has time-stamped rows.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about hardware specifications and or reviews (read: http://meta.blender.stackexchange.com/questions/1/what-questions-should-be-definitely-off-topic)

Comment: We are cautious to avoid specific hardware questions, but I think this question got pummelled into the ground unfairly based on the technicality that the question includes names of hardware as examples. This is not an awful question, but please realize that the answer is going to be fluid. What you should have asked, something to the effect of `are there any benchmark test results for cycles that may help inform  my hardware considerations'

Answer (score 11):

Here's a [spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheet/ccc?key=0As2oZAgjSqDCdElkM3l6VTdRQjhTRWhpVS1hZmV3OGc#gid=0) that collates data from many users running the same benchmark scene. The [thread with active discussion](http://blenderartists.org/forum/showthread.php?239480-2.61-Cycles-render-benchmark) and a copy of the scene is at BlenderArtists, This is the best we can do without relying on opinion.

Decide for yourself which gfx card makes sense.

Note: Different OS's, drivers and versions of Blender, can all significantly change render times. So you'll need to take that into consideration when comparing benchmarks.

Comment: Is this spreadsheet regularly updated? If so, then this answer is awesome. Haters gonna hate on questions like this, but I love seeing a good answer.

Comment: @WrayBowling yeah, a couple of updates this week.. at the time of this writing there are over 900 entries, enough to observe a trend.